# How to use postmessage() and content() methods on a cross domain environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the below code that allows me to find the width of an input textbox inside an iframe on my webpage:

```
<iframe src="//www.example.com/" width="70%" height="500" id="frame"></iframe>
<script>
$( "#frame" ).contents().find( "input" ).css( "width" );
</script>
```

And I have this script that I used it in another website that allows me communicate from a child iframe to its parent mainpage

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

// Listening from iframe
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {},false);


// into the sending child
parent.postMessage("SendWidthToParent","*");
```

I want to know how can I compact these two function in one (postmessage and contents), I couldn't manage to set the "contents script" into the "SendWidthToParent"

Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Halcyon The title says "cross domain environment", what do you think?